# Is there is any simulater that triggers gestures events in JavaScript on Windows 7?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, multi-touch

I have enabled the `Emulate Touch Events` option in Chrome's Developer Tools, to test the touch events, it works fine, but when i `pinch in` and `pinch out` the chrome page is not triggering `gesturestart` and `gesturechange` and i am using the [this](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) driver for `multi touch` this is working for image, browser zoom in and zoom out.

Here i am doing anything wrong or chrome wont support multi-touch event? or Is there is any way to emulate the `gestures` event ?

Note: my chrome version is  22.0.1229.79 m

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading the Android SDK, and then accessing your website from the phone emulator (you can pick which Android version to use). You can navigate to your webpage then (if you serve it at localhost:8080 for example with a simple web server), and use it with the emulator. You can use mouse clicks/drags to emulate touch events on the Android emulator, and those should carry over and emulate the `gestures` event.